# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree in SfCalendar

Tags: flutter

I'm custom Calendar with view is CalendarView.week, when I change TimeSlotViewSettings(numberOfDaysInView = 1), I catch error: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree

```
timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(
                  timeInterval: const Duration(minutes: 30),
                  timeIntervalHeight: 90,
                  timeRulerSize: 82,
                  //dayFormat: 'E',
                  timeFormat: 'jm',
                  numberOfDaysInView: 1,
                  timeTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Color(0xff868e96),
                  ),
                  nonWorkingDays: const <int>[
                    DateTime.saturday,
                    DateTime.sunday
                  ],
                ),
```

When I comment this line, I don't catch this error

Comment: Please share the complete snippet of the parent widget as well. I tried running given `TimeSlotViewSettings` locally and it seems to be working for different valid values of `numberOfDaysInView`.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I completely fixed it